# JAVA library for videoconferencing and how to use libjitsi?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, equinox, video-conferencing

In case of a project we need to create a communication in videoconferencing with two PC
under Linux.
We search a library in JAVA to do this.
We found libJitsi base on Jitsi software, witch transmit with XMPP /Jingle.
I don't arrive to run their example which consists of these two classes:

http://bluejimp.com/jitsi/libjitsi/javadoc/org/jitsi/examples/AVTransmit2.html

http://bluejimp.com/jitsi/libjitsi/javadoc/org/jitsi/examples/AVReceive2.html

There is few documentation and it seems a little fuzzy.
Someone knows this library?
then or knows an alternative for the videoconferencing in JAVA?

thank you.

I used Netbeans or Eclipse Java EE.
SDK 1.7

Comment: Libjitsi is probably your best bet for this, but you are right, there is no documentation to speak of. I am working on a project to provide a simple method for programmers to build this kind of software using libjitsi, ice4j and smack. I've only just started, but here it is: https://github.com/bejayoharen/java-bells

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done a project of video conferencing in java using these 2 files-

```
AVTransmit2.java
AVReceive2.java
```

What I understand is that with these 2 file you can communicate with java **jmf** plugin.

**AVTransmit2.java** works as a data capturer from your own webcam and transmit the data to the peer's IP address.

**AVReceive2.java** works as a data receiver from your remote peer and play the data by java jmf plugin.

For more understanding and easy implementation you can have a look at this **open source** project  http://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2013/07/video-conferencing-project-in-java.html

Comment: org.jitsi.examples.AVTransmit2 is different than your AVTransmit2.java file. Your AVTransmit2 file does no use Libjitsi. Also, Libjitsi, and its example file org.jitsi.examples.AVTransmit2, does not use the old JMF plugin. it uses FMJ (freedom for media in Java) for its stream encoding/decoding. Do you know how to render the streams transmitted in org.jitsi.examples.AVTransmit2? I'm kind of stuck on this same problem myself.